# How to Listen to physical buttons inputs (ex: Volume up) inside @Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

i need to listen to the physical buttons inputs state and actively change stuff on the user screen
but im using kotlin and jetpack compose
i found a code that works only in an Activity

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        // Do something
    }
    return true
}
```

the code above works perfectly in main activity but anywhere else it does not
and obviously it does not work in an @Composable function.
is there a way that i can listen to the buttons key press state inside compose?

Comment: The `onKeyDown()` can update state that is used by your composables.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't understand your point. May you show me a working example?

Answer (score 1):

turns out there is an experimental COMPOSE api modifier (.onKeyEvent) that can be used to listen to keyevents.