# How to track physical volume buttons(Volume Up,Volume down) in Android Jetpack Compose @Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack Compose, and I'm creating app that will use volume buttons to say, if user presses volume up button text for example must be true, if user presses volume down text must be set to false

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713493/how-to-listen-to-physical-buttons-inputs-ex-volume-up-inside-composable), I found one not full answer to use `onKeyEvent` method. Because of answer was not full I tried to make it myself because on the internet there were no answers, but it didnt helped me. When I press buttons they aren't tracking.Below is part of my code that I wrote:

```
Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.white_imprint),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .alpha(imageVisible)
                .onKeyEvent {
                    var returnExsp: Boolean = false
                    if (it.key.keyCode.toInt() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {//it is what i tried to do
                        exspresion = false //it is part of another code
                        volumeBtnPressed = true //it is part of another code
                        returnExsp = true
                        println("Volume down") //how i checked tracking of buttons
                        Log.d("@@@@", "Volume down: ") //how i checked tracking of buttons
                        return@onKeyEvent true

                    } else if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
                        exspresion = true
                        volumeBtnPressed = true
                        returnExsp = true
                        Log.d("@@@@", "Volume up: ")
                        return@onKeyEvent true
                    }
                    return@onKeyEvent returnExsp
```

Maybe I made some simple mistakes, can anyone help me please?

Comment: There is no existing modifier for observing Volume Up Key Event. However You can achieve this by overriding `onKeyDown` function of activity and then observing it into your composable with the help of ViewModel or any other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this code

```
@Composable
    fun VolumeButtonsHandler(
       onVolumeUp: () -> Unit,
       onVolumeDown: () -> Unit
    ) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val view = LocalView.current

    DisposableEffect(context) {
        val keyEventDispatcher = ViewCompat.OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerCompat { _, event ->
            when (event.keyCode) {
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP -> {
                    onVolumeUp()
                    true
                }

                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN -> {
                    onVolumeDown()
                    true
                }

                else -> {
                    false
                }
            }
        }

        ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(view, keyEventDispatcher)

        onDispose {
            ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener(view, keyEventDispatcher)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.onKeyEvent` is right direction to look at. However your composable is lacking a focus in order to receive the key event, probably some other composable is focused, either the top parent or maybe the visibility (alpha) of the composable is interrupting the focus internally.

You need to move the `.onKeyEvent { }` to the parent of this image, that should probably never become invisible or use `FocusRequester` to request focus for this `Image` modifier chain.